# How to access users account different from Google API Console?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to write an app with Google Drive SDK on android tablet.
This app will access the google drive space of the account user choose.
I followed the instructions on this link and it worked. https://developers.google.com/drive/auth/android

However, when I tried to access different account from the account I used on Google API console, the app failed.

For example, if I login Google API console with account "a@gmail.com" and do the authorization for my app, and then execute my app and choose "b@gmail.com" to access the google drive space, the access will fail. AS the result , the app could ONLY access "a@gmail.com".

Is this by design? Oris there any way that my app could let user choose the account they want?
Any help is appreciate! Thanks in advance...

Comment: The user authorization is not relevant to who's the owner of the API console project. Any Google account should be able to go through authorization to use your app.

Comment: @Durcu Dogan:
Oh yes, you are right about " Any Google account should be able to go through authorization to use your app."
The root cause that I cannot login might be something else, not because I changed the Google account.
Thanks for your answer, could you re-post comment as an answer?
I want to accept it.

Comment: @BurcuDogan
Oh....I found that I mis-spelled your name. I'm sorry